# OpenTK's Vector2.Length is twice as fast as Vector2.LengthFast

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, opentk, sqrt

The `OpenTK` libraries, and with them, MonoTouch and MonoDroid, contain the method `LengthFast`, which should calculate an approximation of a vector's length without the use of `Math.Sqrt` (which seems to be known as slow). `LengthFast` uses `MathHelper.InverseSqrtFast`, a quite interesting method which should give a fast approximation of the square root (see lines 172 and 196 of http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/_math_helper_8cs_source.html).

I created a small benchmark which invokes both calculations `100'000'000` times, with vector lengths between about 1 and 100.

**On Windows 7 / Intel i7-2600 3.40 GHz, I got:**

`Length`: `2947 ms`

`LengthFast`: `4754 ms`

**On an iPad 3 with MonoTouch, I got:**

`Length`: `51575 ms`

`LengthFast`: `41252 ms`

So, `LengthFast` is much slower on the Intel CPU, on the iPad's ARM it is slightly faster.

**Any explanation for this?** Is that the result of the Intel CPU being able to calculate the square root 'natively' (without the use of software approximation)? Shouldn't `LengthFast` be always faster, at least a little bit?

Comment: If you use MS .NET on Windows you should add a `.net` tag (or ` `mono` tag if you used Mono on Windows) since the question is more targeted at those results than the one for MonoTouch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `Math` members are really fast. Don't try to speed up .NET math code. On a ARM processor it may be faster because there are some missing X86/X86_64 commands which are required for the same implementation on a ARM processor, so the code is different.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe the OpenTK people could optimize `LengthFast` to use `Length` if running on an ARM processor.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of `LengthFast` it's basically the same bit hack as the one in [Quake 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code).

The algorithm is optimized for x86 instructions, not so much for ARM instructions. It's been documented that this algorithm is actually quite a bit slower on ARM:

http://omcfadde.blogspot.com/2011/02/math-function-micro-optimization.html

> Clearly it can be seen that this micro-optimization is an excellent for x86 and x86_64. Don't try it on ARM; it's far slower than just taking the hit on 1.0 / sqrt(x)

**EDIT**

Turns out I read it backwards... could be the JIT messing with your timings. Try invoking `Length` and `LengthFast` once before going into the timed loop to make sure both methods and the `MathHelper` class get initialized and JITted. It shouldn't make that big of a difference, but it's a starting point. There's no JIT with MonoTouch, so it's still going to be a factor.

Comment: The question results shows that the unoptimized code is faster than the optimized version for **Intel** processor. The ARM (w/MonoTouch) behave like you would expect, i.e. the optimization making it faster.

Comment: oh whoops, got it backwards... hmmm that's strange.

Comment: @RobertRouhani I tried it again with your suggestion, i.e. making sure that everything is JITted before the `Stopwatch`es are started. Still about the same results. `Length` is definitely faster than `LengthFast` on x86/.NET/Windows.

Comment: It's possible the JIT takes advantage of SSE instructions and uses the `rsqrtss` instruction, which is supposed to be faster than the "fast" algorithm... I'm going to try and test this out...